# Why are questions sometimes deleted by the Community user?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/coding-marathons-without-office-chair-or-other-office-seating-device/) appears to have been recently deleted.

It shows as

> deleted by Community♦ 17 mins ago

while I don't necessarily understand what this means (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173204/what-does-deleted-by-community-mean)) it seems likely people here voted to delete this question at some point. Unfortunately I cannot find out who these people were given the above message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a rejected migration. The full text of the annotations is:

> migrated from programmers.stackexchange.comFeb 16 at 10:22

> closed as not a real question by mhoran_psprep, jcmeloni, gnat, scaaahu, RhysW Feb 18 at 15:48
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

> deleted by Community♦ 4 hours ago

Rejected migrations are autodeleted.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to rejected migrations, Community will also delete posts that have been deleted by gathering enough spam/offensive flags as well as downvoted, unanswered, closed questions after 30 days (or something like that). Basically any situation where the system auto-deletes a post, Community is listed as the one who pulled the trigger.